# How can we reduce this for loop into minimal LOC?

Tags: python

How can we reduce below piece of code in python to its minimal line of code?

```
def calculate_diff(actual, pred):
    actual = np.array(actual)/255
    pred = np.array(pred) / 255
    mean_ = sum(actual)/len(actual)
    denom = nume = 0
    for ac, pr in zip(actual, pred):
        denom = denom + (ac - mean_)**2
        nume = nume + (pr - ac)**2
    return (nume/denom)**(1/2)

calculate_diff([0, 10, 50, 10, 200, 250], [0, 10, 50, 10, 200, 250])
```

I am trying to find RRSE mentioned in the page:
https://www.gepsoft.com/GeneXproTools/AnalysesAndComputations/MeasuresOfFit/RootRelativeSquaredError.htm

Comment: I am trying to find RRSE of two arrays. writing loops will take time so minimizing the code.

Comment: I have updated the question can you please take back negative votes?
@wwii

Comment: `denom,nume = map(sum, zip(*[(pow(ac-mean_,2),(pow(pr-ac,2))) for ac,pr in zip(actual,pred)]))` OR `denom,nume = map(sum, zip(*((pow(ac-mean_,2),(pow(pr-ac,2))) for ac,pr in zip(actual,pred))))`

Comment: However with Numpy ndarrays: `denom = np.square(actual-actual.mean()).sum(); nume = np.square(pred-actual).sum(); RRSE = pow(nume/denom, .5)` - you can make one long line of all that if you need.

Comment: Thank You @wwii. This was helpful. It seems I have to implement this in tensorflow so looking for the inspiration.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: Yes AMC I have tried multiple things and I am not asking directly major issues I have faced is when we have to reduce the whole list and one line needed (pr and ac) both. I have worked a lot before posting here. and actually I can not mark wwii's comment otherwise that is the best version of code I have ever seen. I feel your comment was little rude. Irrespective of knowing history one should not comment abruptly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with `minimal LOC`.

Since you are using Numpy ndarrays in your function, here is an equivalent without a for loop.

```
def calculate_diff(actual, pred):
    actual = np.array(actual)/255
    pred = np.array(pred) / 255
    denom = np.square(actual-actual.mean()).sum()
    nume = np.square(pred-actual).sum()
    return (nume/denom) ** .5
```

Comment: Correct solution is mentioned by you in comment section of question:
However with Numpy ndarrays: denom = np.square(actual-actual.mean()).sum(); nume = np.square(pred-actual).sum(); RRSE = pow(nume/denom, .5) - you can make one long line of all that if you need.